# how to completely remove tab indicator in an ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I use an `ActionBar` in my `FragmentActivity` (min SDK = 14) and I need to remove the active Tab indicator (see picture below) since I have my own icons for indicating which Tab is active. I've been reading a lot of style-related stuff, found no solution however. Any suggestions how this indicator can be completely removed?

[image]

**SOLVED**

The working solution is below:

```
      <style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and then adding to the Activity style:

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to change the color of tab 'underbar' in actionbarsherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273888/how-to-change-the-color-of-tab-underbar-in-actionbarsherlock), looks like the indicator is a part of a drawable. I haven't tried that but you probably can change @drawable/tab_selected and @drawable/tab_selected_focused to your own drawable. (Make it plain if you don't want the indicator.) Hope this helps.

Edit:

**NOTE: HAVEN'T TESTED**

You can try following [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273888/how-to-change-the-color-of-tab-underbar-in-actionbarsherlock) and change from tab_selected_focused to tab_unselected_focused and also from tab_selected to tab_unselected.

```
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />

 <!-- Focused states -->
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused" />
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused" />
```

Edit 2:
You can try ActionbarStyleGenerator to style the Actionbar.

> "How to:
>   Use the UI to select colors for different items
>   Once done click on "DOWNLOAD .ZIP"
>   The ZIP file contains resource files that you have to copy in your project res/layout and res/drawableXXXX folders"

Comment: thanks, in your linked answer I found a link to a style generator, I changed the indicator color and was able to find the required parameters in the downloaded .zip. Updating question so it could help someone else

Comment: Great. I'll update my answer and add that for the future reference.