# How to customize tabs actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

Basically I want to make tabs in actionbar look like this: (notice this is actionbar, not tabhost)

[image]

Here is what I have so far:
[image]

As you can see the problems is that the padding between the tabs is too large, it doesn't fit the whole screen. Making the tab bars slidable. I want the tab to be fixed (not slidable).

How could I do that ? How could i fix the padding of the tabbar?

Thank you for reading the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the tab indicator present in your action bar tabs you can try like
[Remove tab Indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18386060/1937802).

and for more customization try with this [Actionbar style generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to move tab indicator down for 5 dp, because as you can see on my version, the tab indicator override text. Or even better, how do I make the indicator like in the picture, meaning just gray out the back ground. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098206/change-actionbar-height-on-android-jellybean refer this

Comment: Thank you,  that's exactly what i want to do, but the solution they provide doesn't work for me ( as for some other guys on the thread there also ). I tried:
<item name="android:actionBarSize">100dp</item>
<item name="actionBarSize">100dp</item>

Answer (score 1):

You should use Support.v4.pagerslider or pager sliding tab strip

using actionbar tab is waste of time if you want customise here is the code

[use below link to style actionbar](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator)

You need to change tab_indicator_ab_example.xml inside drawable like below

```
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

     <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" 
         android:state_focused="false" 
         android:state_pressed="false" 
         android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/layer_bg_selected_tabs_green" 
    android:state_focused="false" 
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/layer_bg_selected_tabs_green" 
    android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- Pressed -->
<!-- Non focused states -->
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" 
     android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
     android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/layer_bg_selected_tabs_green" 
    android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/layer_bg_selected_tabs_green" 
    android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:state_selected="true"/>
     </selector>
```

create xml layer_bg_selected_tabs_green.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- code for tab indicator -->
 <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#F58634" />
        <padding android:bottom="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

change indicator here and padding chnages height Solid changes color of indicator

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did this by override the style of the action bar:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">false</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Hope this help anyone come across this problem :).