# Disable ActionBar tab indicator programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-tabs

Is it possible to disable the tab indicator using programmatically/ Java code ?
This is how I am setting other tab properties :

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")));
```

`ActionBar.TabListener` methods :

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        try {
            if (tab.getPosition() == 4) {
                listFlyout = null;
                pwindo = null;
                items.clear();
                addFlyout();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#10A595"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                selectedTabIndex = tab.getPosition();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {                 tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#F25252"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                selectedTabIndex = tab.getPosition();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.DKGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                selectedTabIndex = tab.getPosition();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 3) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.DKGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                selectedTabIndex = tab.getPosition();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        if (tab.getPosition() == 4) {
            listFlyout = null;
            pwindo = null;
            items.clear();
            addFlyout();
        }
    }
```

But I am getting **green** tab indicator which I don't want.

[image]

Comment: Please provide your setOnPageChangeListener() code.

Comment: @AvishekDas : Why Will that be required ? I do have ActionBar.TabListener implemented though. I have updated my question wherein you can view that.

Comment: On this listner method a function has called onPageSelected this function is handle it

Comment: @AvishekDas : Could you please explain how setOnPageChangeListener() will handle this ?

Comment: Check this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384727/how-to-completely-remove-tab-indicator-in-an-actionbar)

Comment: @Xcihnegn : As I mentioned, I don't want to apply this on style.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Applying the style as answered [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339797/actionbar-tabs-set-dynamic-width-according-to-screen-width) disabled the indicator as well. One solution fixed two issues for me :)

Comment: you mentioned:  **I don't want to disable the tab indicator using styles.** anyway if you do not want to give bounty you can but please specify your question exactly and then ask for help.

Comment: @mmlooloo : I was not even thinking about fixing this issue when I was changing the style. I was changing it to check some other issue and even this one got fixed. I have not awarded you the bounty because I can't use third party classes. You are right though about my question of not using style. So I have edited it now.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would not use `ActionBar` tab because it is deprecated from api 21 and also it is not working on tablets as you may expect. I would use

1)[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

2)[SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)

(another version of SlidingTabsBasic is [here](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget) you must add  `SlidingTabLayout.java` and `SlidingTabStrip.java`)

If you want to use [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) you can use `pstsIndicatorColor` or

```
public void setIndicatorColor(int indicatorColor) 

public void setIndicatorColorResource(int resId)
```

from the library.

If you want to use `SlidingTabsBasic` you can use

```
SlidingTabLayout tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs); 
tabs.setViewPager(viewpager); 

tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {

    @Override
    public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
    return getResources().getColor(R.color.white);  
    }

    @Override
    public int getDividerColor(int position) {
    return getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
    }
});
```