# How to remove the tab indicator on Android

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Can anyone tell me how to remove tab indicator in android? (i.e the blue colour line under tabs).

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: There are multiple threads on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384727/how-to-completely-remove-tab-indicator-in-an-actionbar , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384727/how-to-completely-remove-tab-indicator-in-an-actionbar , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672302/how-do-i-remove-the-selected-tab-indicator-from-the-tabwidget